# Creating a "Page to Source" report in GA4

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, I had several custom reports I loved in the previous version, but the one I'm missing the most is one where I was able to click the link (or title, it doesn't matter which) to a specific page on my website and on the next page or drill down, it would show me where traffic to the page came from. I had to even drill-down to some other analytics that I was curious about.

Here is the image I saved in my notes:
[image]

There don't appear to be very robust referral reports native to GA4. How would I go about creating this report? GA4 is still unfortunately very foreign to me.